# Squash commits (with merges) from one branch into another

Tags: git

I'm working on a project with a particular git project repository. There are three branches:

1. `master`
2. `development`
3. `release`

The structure is as follows: from `master` spawns `development`, where features are developed and tested. Once a set of features has been developed, `development` is merged (no fast-forward) into `master`, and that merge commit represents either a release version or an intermediate version. Nothing gets directly committed to `master`, it only consists of merge commits from `development`.

When a version is considered a release version, it needs to be moved somehow to `release`. The idea is that `release` has a linear history in which each commit represents a release version. There should be no trace of any intermediate commits in `release`.

Take this example: `release/01.03.00.00` represents the same repository state as `master/01.03.00.00`. I now want to create a single commit in `release` which represents the difference between `master/01.04.00.00` and `master/01.03.00.00`. **Can it be done without using `git patch`?** Using `git cherry-pick` with a range of commits (take into account that sometimes there can be several merge commits in `master` between release versions) did not seem to work (it required `-m` in order to deal with merge commits but would then complain about not-merge commits).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a repo to test this but, have you tried creating a branch from master, squash all commits of that new branch, and *then* merge that into release?

Something like:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch -b tmp-master
$ git rebase -i HASH # the hash of the first commit from master you want to bring into release
# pick the last commit, squash all other commits
$ git checkout release
$ git cherry-pick HASH # put the hash of the commit you just made in tmp-master
```